# What is advantage of using @value annotation in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am new to `Spring Boot` and I am doing code cleanup for my old `Spring Boot` application.
Below code is using `@Value` annotation to inject filed value from properties file.

```
@Value("${abc.local.configs.filepath}")
private String LOCAL_ABC_CONFIGS_XML_FILEPATH;
```

My doubt is instead of getting value from properties file, can we not directly hardcode the value in same java class variable?

**Example:** `private String LOCAL_ABC_CONFIGS_XML_FILEPATH="/abc/config/abc.txt"`

It would be easier for me to modify the values in future as it will be in same class.

What is advantage of reading from properties file, does it make the code decoupled ?

Comment: And what if you want the file on your production machines to be in a different location? You recompile the code specially for production and basically go live with an untested artifact? Making it externalized allows you to override it per deployment/environment/profile/...

Comment: @M.Deinum absolutely you build and deploy to your environment when you need to tweak something, makes changes tracked, integration tests passed and rollbacks simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technique is called as `externalising configurations`. You are absolutely right that you can have your constants defined in the very same class files. But, sometimes, your configurations are volatile or may change with respect to the environment being deployed to.

*For Example:*

**Scene 1:**
I have a variables for DB connection details which will change with the environment. Remember, you will create a build out of your application and deploy it first to Dev, then take same build to stage and finally to the production.

Having your configurations defined externally, helps you to pre-define them at environment level and have same build being deployed everywhere.

**Scene 2:**
You have already generated a build and deployed and found something was incorrect with the constants. Having those configurations externalised gives you a liberty to just override it on environment level and change without rebuilding your application.

To understand more about externalising techniques read: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Answer (score 1):

Here @value is used for reading the values from properties file (it could be a any environment like dev, qa, prod) but we are writing @value on multiple fields it is not recomonded so thats instead of @value we can use @configurableProperties(prefix="somevalue>)  and read the property values suppose `

```
    @configurableProperties(prefix="somevalue")
        class Foo{
        string name;
        string address;
        }

application.properties:  
somevalue.name="your name"    
somevalue.address="your address"
```

`